# Calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a 2x2 complex matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-mathematics, matrix-equations

I've previously asked elsewhere, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118820/non-trivial-eigenvectors-of-a-22-matrix-in-code, how to calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix in a programming language. I am still working with a 2x2 matrix ($A$) but it's now complex, and takes the form:
$$
        A = \begin{bmatrix}
        a+jb & c + jd \\
        e + jf & g +jh \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $j$ is the square root of $-1$.

Do the equations in http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21b_fall_04/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html (which is used as a part of the solution in the previous link) still hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the formula does still work. It was found by solving the quadratic equation, and polynomials with complex coefficients can be factored in this way.